# Samba used to work until I switched to wifi

Tags: samba, shared-folders

I have 2 systems: 1 media player WDTV Live (wifi) and 1 desktop (wired). The media player could access my video database until I switched my desktop to wifi. Now the media player can't even find the system.

What has happened ? How can I fix this ?

Samba config: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23353418/

Network info: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23353410/

Answer (score 0):

Check your wireless router configuration.  Sometimes, they have a setting called 'Wireless Isolation' or 'AP Isolation' mode (under advanced wireless settings).  This setting limits what wireless clients can see to just the AP.  I know I've seen it in SonicWall and Asus products.

Also, make sure that your your media player is not on a Guest network (same reason as above).

Also, please make sure your wifi (server and clients) are configured for the correct region.  I had an issue where my router was set to central Europe frequencies, but my clients were set to North America.  (Tomato firmware by Shibby - it rocked).  The wifi *almost* worked; I could see other shares and browse the Internet - sometimes - but streaming and file copying never worked.

In your Samba conf file, I notice that you said your network is a 192.168.1.0/15 - that's a big block.  Let me break out the [CIDR calculator...](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php)
Mmm, bad news, that's an invalid block...  Best I can figure, that's 192.168.0.0/15, or 192.168.0.0 to 192.16**9**.255.255. Your private block is bleeding over into the public Internet. You should not use lower than a /16 for the 192.168.0.0/16 private block.  The Class B private range is 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255.  FWIW, most consumer stuff is hard coded not to recognize anything other than a Class C network (/24), so keep that in mind when configuring your network.

Now, set that subnet back down to a more reasonable /24, so 192.168.1.0/24 (that's the 255.255.255.0 subnet), and maybe Samba will play nice again.  Whatever it is set to, make the rest of the network configuration needs to match that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have no access to my advanced wireless settings, will have to contact my provider to check it out.

Media player is not on a guest network, both the pc and media player are connected to the 2.4ghz network.

Where can I find the settings for region for the ubuntu server ? I never seen anything like this. Do I do it for samba or for the computer ?

In the Samba.conf file, that line is commented out. I have no idea how I made my Samba share work, I just kept working with the shared folder thing and it magically worked. I'll try commenting it out.